# if else statement not working correctly in html

Tags: html, if-statement

I am working on a webpage for a non-profit and the if else statement for the webpage is not working correctly.  I am not the best programmer and am unsure what I did wrong.  The webpage is supposed to ask for a zip code to be typed into a text box and then send the person to the correct outside webpage associated with that zip code.  Currently, it is not going to the outside webpage or even showing the else statement.  So I am doing something wrong in the if else statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Find your nearest Meeting </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><b>Finding your nearest meeting</b></h1>
<p>When leaving your treatment center and going back home, it is importaint to find your nearest AA meeting as soon as possible.<br>
The Area 26 Treatment Committee wants to make this easy for you.  
Please type in your zipcode <b><i>OR</i></b> your city <b><i>OR</i></b> your county in <i><u>one</u></i> of the boxes below.<br>
You will then be directed to the Intergroup meeting webpage that serves that area. 
Here you will be able to locate a meeting and continue your journey in sobrity.<br>
Remeber, <i>We shall be with you in the Fellowship of the Spirit, and you will surely meet some of us as you trudge the
Road of Happy Destiny.</i>
</p>
<br>
<label for="Zipcode">Zipcode:</label>
<input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode">
<p id="Zipcode"></p>
<br><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var a=document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
if(a=="40342") {
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page"; 
<a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/, ‘newwindow’)
}
else if(a=="40358")
{
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page"; 
<a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/, ‘newwindow’)
}
else
{
document.getElementById("Zipcode").innerHTML="I'm sorry but we have not found an Intergroup Meeting Page that has meetings in that area. Please go to the Area 26 meeting page for a list of meetings in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
<a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting"> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
window.open(https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting, ‘newwindow’)
```

Comment: why you mixing html with javascript code? removes the `<a href...></a>`stuff from the code and add `"`inside the `window.open("https://...", "_blank")`. If you would look at the developer console, you should see syntax errors when loading your current page :)

Comment: There are so many issues despite the typos. `b` inside an `h1` makes nos sense. Instead of using `br` you should read into margins. br is to break a flow text to the next line not to create visual gaps for which you have padding and margins. The usage of innerHTML is outdated for performance and security reasons. Id's must be unique and can not used multiple times. a `p` is no replacement for an `output`. You should read into switch statements instead of using `if/else in your cases. In modern JS you should use external JS and use event listeners over the outdated `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score -2):

not putting strings in quote marks "string"

not closing the ending curly brace on last else statement

no closing </script> </body> </html> tags

using ’ instead of '

fixed version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Find your nearest Meeting </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1><b>Finding your nearest meeting</b></h1>
    <p>When leaving your treatment center and going back home, it is importaint to find your nearest AA meeting as soon
        as possible.<br>
        The Area 26 Treatment Committee wants to make this easy for you.
        Please type in your zipcode <b><i>OR</i></b> your city <b><i>OR</i></b> your county in <i><u>one</u></i> of the
        boxes below.<br>
        You will then be directed to the Intergroup meeting webpage that serves that area.
        Here you will be able to locate a meeting and continue your journey in sobrity.<br>
        Remeber, <i>We shall be with you in the Fellowship of the Spirit, and you will surely meet some of us as you
            trudge the
            Road of Happy Destiny.</i>
    </p>
    <br>
    <label for="Zipcode">Zipcode:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Zipcode" name="Zipcode">
    <p id="Zipcode_text"></p>
    <br><br><br>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var a = document.getElementById("Zipcode").value;
            if (a == "40342") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page";
                // <a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/", 'newwindow')
            }
            else if (a == "40358") {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "Thank you. You will be directed to the Bluegrass Intergroup’s Meeting page";
                // <a href="https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/"> Bluegrass Intergroup Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("https://www.bluegrassintergroup.org/meetings/", 'newwindow')
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Zipcode_text").innerHTML = "I'm sorry but we have not found an Intergroup Meeting Page that has meetings in that area. Please go to the Area 26 meeting page for a list of meetings in Kentucky, Southern Indiana and Ohio.";
                // <a href="https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting"> Area 26 Find A Meeting Page</a>;
                window.open("https://www.area26.net/wp/?post_type=tsml_meeting", 'newwindow')
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```